Equivalence of $\sum_{i=1}^3 \sum_{j=1}^3 k_j Cov[y_i, x_j]$ and $\sum_{i=1}^3 k_j\sum_{j=1}^3 Cov[y_i, x_j]$
We define two correlated random variables $Y_i$ and $X_j$ and say we have this sample, $Y_i:\{y_1,y_2,y_3\}$ and $X_j:\{x_1,x_2,x_3\}$ for the convenience of illustration.
I want to calculate $Cov[\sum_1^3 y_i , \sum_1^3 k_jx_j]$, where $k_j \in \mathbb{R}$, meaning $k_j$ is just an indexed real number. What I've got so far:
\begin{align}
Cov[\sum_1^3 y_i , \sum_1^3 k_jx_j] &= Cov[ (y_1 + y_2 + y_3  ), (k_1x_1 + k_2x_2+k_3x_3)] \\
&= Cov[y_1, k_1x_1] + Cov[y_1, k_2x_2] + Cov[y_1, k_3x_3]\\
&+ Cov[y_2, k_1x_1] + Cov[y_2, k_2x_2] + Cov[y_2, k_3x_3]\\
&+ Cov[y_3, k_1x_1] + Cov[y_3, k_2x_2] + Cov[y_3, k_3x_3]\\
&= k_1Cov[y_1, x_1] + k_2Cov[y_1, x_2] + k_3Cov[y_1, x_3]\\
&+ k_1Cov[y_2, x_1] + k_2Cov[y_2, x_2] + k_3Cov[y_2, x_3]\\
&+ k_1Cov[y_3, x_1] + k_2Cov[y_3, x_2] + k_3Cov[y_3, x_3]
\end{align}
It can be readily seen that $Cov[\sum_1^3 y_i , \sum_1^3 k_jx_j]$ can be equivalently rewritten as
$\sum_{i=1}^3 \sum_{j=1}^3 k_j Cov[y_i, x_j] $ as the following shows:
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^3 \sum_{j=1}^3 k_j Cov[y_i, x_j] 
&= \sum_{i=1}^3 k_1Cov[y_i, x_1] +k_2Cov[y_i, x_2]+ k_3Cov[y_i, x_3] \\
&= k_1Cov[y_1, x_1] +k_2Cov[y_1, x_2]+ k_3Cov[y_1, x_3] \\
&+ k_1Cov[y_2, x_1] +k_2Cov[y_2, x_2]+ k_3Cov[y_2, x_3]\\
&+k_1Cov[y_3, x_1] +k_2Cov[y_3, x_2]+ k_3Cov[y_3, x_3]
\end{align}
My question is if $Cov[\sum_1^3 y_i , \sum_1^3 k_jx_j]$ can even be factorized as $\sum_{i=1}^3 k_j\sum_{j=1}^3 Cov[y_i, x_j]$.
I understand in the case of OLS-regression where $Cov[y_i, y_j]=\sigma^2$, then we can factor out $\sum_{i=1}^3 k_j$, which results in $Cov[\sum_1^3 y_i , \sum_1^3 k_jy_j]=\sum_{i=1}^3 k_j\sum_{j=1}^3 Cov[y_i, y_j]=\sum_{i=1}^3 k_j 3\sigma^2$. I wonder if this equality holds in more general cases as I've presented above in the form of $Cov[y_i, x_j]$.
